# "No connection" issue with Steam, disconnect causing to drop out of multiplayer - Steam client restarts are constantly required

Tags: steam

Every now and then Steam loses connection and doesn't reconnected afterwards, I've tried waiting for hours at most. The only way to reconnect is to restart the Steam client as far as I know. When the connection drops during a multiplayer game, I'm instantly thrown out. When I have "no connection", I can browse Steam Store and Community pages for some reason, but can't join Steamworks multiplayer games.

**This can't be related to Steam maintenance or server outage** as I can instantly reconnect by restarting Steam, or wait infinitely for connection.

[image: No connection]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was caused by changed DNS servers.

Comment: OP: I actually believe this question is on-topic still, so I'm going to vote to leave it open. Generally speaking it leaves a bad taste in my mouth to VTC a question based on its answer.

Comment: @Schism: I don't vote based on answer, the answer is decent. I want to close the question because it is misleading and can harm Valve's reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas (some of them might be completely wrong):

1. Your session might be timing out. Did you mark the "remember me" checkbox when logging in to steam?
2. Someone might be trying to log in on your account on a different machine. Try changing your password and enabling Steam Guard.
3. Your firewall or other security software might be interfering. Try adding a firewall exception for Steam in your firewall.
4. Your Steam installation might be corrupt. Try completely closing steam, then delete everything in your steam folder EXCEPT steam.exe, the steamapps folder and the UserData folder, then start Steam again. If that fails, you'll have to move the steamapps folder to another location, COMPLETELY delete the steam folder and reinstall from a fresh download.
5. (as said by the OP) your DNS servers might be configured incorrectly. Try using the Google DNS servers (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844 for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively), or the DNS servers your ISP gives.

Comment: The issue was caused by changed DNS server.

Comment: What does that mean? Having the same issue and can't figure it out.